# Codeigniter URL routing solution for my website

Tags: codeigniter, routes

I have a website that is developed with CodeIgniter. I have added the route for my url as follows:

```
$route['about_us'] = 'about-us';
```

Now I have a problem with that. I.e. when I am looking for the url www.mysite.com/about_us it works and at same time www.mysite.com/about-us is also working. I want only one url to work: the one with the underscore.

I have removed this to:

```
$route['about_us'] = 'about-us';
```

But the url www.mysite.com/about-us still works. It may cause duplicate content for my website in Google and so more page links also showing. Even I don't have that functions too. Like www.mysite.com/about_us/design. Likewise in about_us controller file index function only there, but design method calling in Google.

How do I resolve this problem?

Comment: With no routing rules at all and the controller named `about_us` is the hyphenated URL working?

Comment: If you really care about SEO, You should be using dashes instead of underscores in URLS. http://blog.woorank.com/2013/04/underscores-in-urls-why-are-they-not-recommended/ . I.E. This pages url ^

Comment: I'm caring about seo onluy.. If two urls so same content means it will cause duplication.. I want either underscore or hyphen.. If underscore working then hyphen will not work. or hyphen will work underscore will not work..i wnat solution for this

Answer (score 1):

You actually don't need a route here. The normal purpose of request routing the way you are using it is so that you can use hyphenated URLs when hyphens are not permitted in class and function names. I.E. you want the url to by `www.example.com/test-controller`, but you can't actually name a controller `test-controller` because the hyphen is illegal.

If you only want to have the underscored URL such as `www.mysite.com/about_us` then just remove the route completely and name the controller `about_us`. With no routing rules the hyphenated url should 404.

Comment: I have removed the route completely but the url not showing 404 page it's showing the about_us page :(

Comment: What is your controller class named? Also do you have any `mod_rewrite` rules in any of your `.htaccess` files that might be rewriting the URL?

Comment: my controller name is about_us. I want solution for when i was put the address bar with about_us only working. If i put about-us it will show 404 ..this is i want ..any one give the solution please

Comment: If there are no routes in place it should already be showing a 404 error unless there is some odd rewrite or config option set somewhere that is rerouting it. One thing you can do alternatively is explicitly route the bad url to a controller that doesn't exist. You shouldn't need to do this at all but it can be accomplished with the route `$route['about-us.*'] = 'void';` provided `void` isn't a controller name.

Comment: Again, this should not be necessary at all, but this route will redirect ANY URI containing a hyphen to 404. Use with care. Edit: damn enter button, one sec

Comment: I want either underscore or hyphen.. If underscore working then hyphen will not work. or hyphen will work underscore will not work..i wnat solution for this

Comment: `$route['.*-+?.*'] = 'void';` That route will cause any URI containing a hypen to redirect to a 404. It's 1:30 AM here so this will be my last response until morning, sorry.

Comment: @user2484538 Select this as your accepted answer using the check mark to the left of the answer, if this answered your question.  It's common courtesy to do so on StackOverflow.